# error CS0121: Problem with automapper when compile

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

so mapper doesn't work in my project

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

error:

> Startup.cs(112,21): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection, params Assembly[])' and 'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection, params Type[])' [/Users/admin/Desktop/YP/youplay/server/YouPlay.Api/YouPlay.Api.csproj]

When i change to:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

It's compile, but, when i trying to make req to

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<BetOpenForm>> CreateBetAsync([FromBody]CreateBetForm bet)
    {
        BetOpenForm response;
        try
        {

            BetOpen newBet = await _betService.CreateBetOpenAsync(bet);
           response = _mapper.Map<BetOpenForm>(newBet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
           // return new BadRequestObjectResult(new ApiError("Something gone wrong ;("));
             return new BadRequestObjectResult(new ApiError(ex.Message));
        }

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

I getting:

[image]

Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YouPlay.Api.Controllers.ViewModels.Bet
{
    public class BetOpenForm
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int StreamId { get; set; }
        public List<BetOptionForm> BetOptions { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;

namespace YouPlay.Api.Controllers.ViewModels.Bet
{
    public class BetOptionForm
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string BetOpenId { get; set; }
        public string OptionText { get; set; }
        public double Odd { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public int BetsCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Of course i have a lot of Controllers, which inject automapper - when i use services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup)) - it's not error, but later mapper doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```